# SQL: SUM the MAX values of results returned

Tags: mysql, sql, select, sum, max

The following SQL statement produces the results listed below. Question is, how do I modify this statement to provide just the total sum of individual values which is **6,940**?

```
SELECT 
post_metrics.post_id,
post_metric_types.name, 
MAX(post_metrics.value)
FROM post_metrics 
INNER JOIN post_metric_types ON post_metric_types.id = post_metrics.post_metric_type_id 
LEFT JOIN posts ON posts.id = post_metrics.post_id
WHERE post_metrics.post_metric_type_id = 2
AND posts.channel_id = 2268
GROUP BY post_metrics.post_id 
ORDER BY post_metrics.post_metric_type_id, post_metrics.post_id, post_metrics.value DESC
```

POSTID: VALUE;

1: 25; 2: 588; 3: 12; 4: 0; 5: 74; 6: 12; 7: 4; 8: 27; 9: 13; 10: 70; 11: 0; 12: 28; 13: 0; 14: 204; 15: 181; 16: 101; 17: 17; 18: 19; 19: 0; 20: 171; 21: 37; 22: 72; 23: 25; 24: 82; 25: 81; 26: 164; 27: 0; 28: 37; 29: 215; 30: 6; 31: 0; 32: 203; 33: 10; 34: 7; 35: 29; 36: 71; 37: 39; 38: 8; 39: 0; 40: 28; 41: 4; 42: 35; 43: 44; 44: 9; 45: 0; 46: 18; 47: 125; 48: 6; 49: 30; 50: 0; 51: 6; 52: 11; 53: 8; 54: 74; 55: 0; 56: 10; 57: 8; 58: 11; 59: 0; 60: 12; 61: 15; 62: 0; 63: 108; 64: 9; 65: 72; 66: 24; 67: 0; 68: 19; 69: 86; 70: 0; 71: 16; 72: 25; 73: 10; 74: 23; 75: 12; 76: 23; 77: 10; 78: 0; 79: 0; 80: 101; 81: 141; 82: 14; 83: 0; 84: 5; 85: 43; 86: 36; 87: 0; 88: 9; 89: 22; 90: 14; 91: 10; 92: 17; 93: 6; 94: 3; 95: 0; 96: 9; 97: 9; 98: 0; 99: 67; 100: 18; 101: 10; 102: 3; 103: 0; 104: 7; 105: 0; 106: 9; 107: 13; 108: 3; 109: 10; 110: 27; 111: 14; 112: 60; 113: 22; 114: 11; 115: 10; 116: 0; 117: 15; 118: 11; 119: 20; 120: 0; 121: 42; 122: 26; 123: 0; 124: 15; 125: 30; 126: 4; 127: 66; 128: 9; 129: 35; 130: 5; 131: 0; 132: 17; 133: 0; 134: 616; 135: 5; 136: 6; 137: 0; 138: 4; 139: 24; 140: 5; 141: 0; 142: 5; 143: 710; 144: 0; 145: 30; 146: 6; 147: 25; 148: 4; 149: 7; 150: 6; 151: 0; 152: 28; 153: 6; 154: 9; 155: 0; 156: 10; 157: 4; 158: 2; 159: 0; 160: 0; 161: 51; 162: 10; 163: 6; 164: 35; 165: 6; 166: 2; 167: 0; 168: 0; 169: 13; 170: 5; 171: 4; 172: 3; 173: 9; 174: 8; 175: 3; 176: 0; 177: 19; 178: 45; 179: 0; 180: 27; 181: 0; 182: 13; 183: 8; 184: 9; 185: 5; 186: 0; 187: 103; 188: 4; 189: 12; 190: 5; 191: 10; 192: 8; 193: 5; 194: 6; 195: 6; 196: 6; 197: 6; 198: 87; 199: 4; 200: 55; 201: 30; 202: 9; 203: 32; 204: 9; 205: 0; 206: 10; 207: 0; 208: 29; 209: 11; 210: 10; 211: 4; 212: 0; 213: 44; 214: 101;

= 6,904

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using your existing query as a subquery would be one way:

```
SELECT SUM(maxpostmetric)
FROM (
    SELECT 
        post_metrics.post_id,
        post_metric_types.name, 
        MAX(post_metrics.value) maxpostmetric
    FROM post_metrics 
        INNER JOIN post_metric_types ON post_metric_types.id = post_metrics.post_metric_type_id 
        LEFT JOIN posts ON posts.id = post_metrics.post_id
    WHERE post_metrics.post_metric_type_id = 2
        AND posts.channel_id = 2268
    GROUP BY post_metrics.post_id 
) t
```

Good luck.

BTW -- You're using a `LEFT JOIN` on your posts table, but then including a column from that table in your `WHERE` criteria.  You could just turn that into an `INNER JOIN`.

Answer (score 2):

Run a query over your current query:

```
select sum(max_value)
from (SELECT 
    post_metrics.post_id,
    post_metric_types.name, 
    MAX(post_metrics.value) as max_value
    FROM ...
) x
```