# Trying to to do a Sum(MAX) calculation in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

Thanks for all the help that you all provided and though it was an eye opener unfortunately it did not produce the expected results I was looking for.  In an effort to better get the help I'm looking for I will try to explain what I'm looking to achieve.

I think the main columns of focus are "IN", "AA_Now", "STF_Now", "dbo.Sheet1$.LOB_name", "dbo.Sheet1$.LifeCycleName" and "dbo.Sheet1$.AreaOfBusiness". Each "IN" have an "AA_Now" and "STF_Now". A group of "IN" rolls up under "dbo.Sheet1$.LOB_name".  Under "dbo.Sheet1$.LOB_name" I just want the max value of the Group of "IN" that is rolled up. Now "dbo.Sheet1$.LOB_name" is rolled up under "dbo.Sheet1$.LifeCycleName" and what I want is the sum of of the max values that are rolled up under "dbo.Sheet1$.LOB_name" to show in the rollup of "dbo.Sheet1$.LifeCycleName". Finally "dbo.Sheet1$.LifeCycleName" rolls up to "dbo.Sheet1$.AreaOfBusiness". As before what I'm looking for is the sum of "dbo.Sheet1$.LifeCycleName" to show.  These are only for the columns of "AA_Now" and "STF_Now" 
I tried doing it from a Pivot table but to no avail and figured that it would be best to sort it out in the raw data.

I'm trying to to do a SUM(MAX) calculation in SQL server and getting the follow error when executing the command

> Msg 130, Level 15, State 1, Line 6
>   Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.

I'm sure the error is caused by both

> ,SUM(MAX(convert(float,replace([AA_Now], 'N/A','0')))) As [AA2_Now]

and

> ,SUM(MAX(convert(float,replace([STF_Now], 'N/A','0')))) As [STF2_Now]

but have no idea how to rewrite it without causing an error.

Below is the full code.

```
SELECT  dbo.CCA_Merged.id, dbo.CCA_Merged.timeStamp, dbo.CCA_Merged.name, dbo.CCA_Merged.lN
        ,dbo.CCA_Merged.type, dbo.CCA_Merged.id2, dbo.CCA_Merged.aG 
        ,dbo.CCA_Merged.regionId, dbo.CCA_Merged.sgcc       
        ,convert(float,replace([SLC_Today],'N/A','0')) As [SLC_Today]
        ,convert(float,replace([AA_Now],'N/A','0')) As [AA_Now]
        ,SUM(MAX(convert(float,replace([AA_Now],'N/A','0')))) As [AA2_Now]
        ,convert(float,replace([SLCO_Today],'N/A','0')) As [SLCO_Today]
        ,convert(float,replace([CABN_Today],'N/A','0')) As [CABN_Today]
        ,convert(float,replace([COF_Today],'N/A','0')) As [COF_Today]
        ,convert(float,replace([HT_Today],'N/A','0')) As [HT_Today]
        ,convert(float,replace(replace([CH_Today],'N/A','0'),'-','0')) As [CH_Today]
        ,convert(float,replace([SLC_Now],'N/A','0')) As [SLC_Now]
        ,convert(float,replace([SLCO_Now],'N/A','0')) As [SLCO_Now]
        ,convert(float,replace([SLC_Thirty],'N/A','0')) As [SLC_Thirty]
        ,convert(float,replace(replace([SLCO_Thirty],'N/A','0'),'-','0')) As [SLCO_Thirty]
        ,convert(float,replace([ACWT_Today],'N/A','0')) As [ACWT_Today]
        ,convert(float,replace([CQ_Now],'N/A','0')) As [CQ_Now]
        ,convert(float,replace([LCQ_Now],'N/A','0')) As [LCQ_Now]
        ,convert(float,replace([SLCH_Now],'N/A','0')) As [SLCH_Now]
        ,convert(float,replace([STF_Now],'N/A','0')) As [STF_Now]
        ,SUM(MAX(convert(float,replace([STF_Now],'N/A','0')))) As [STF2_Now]
        ,dbo.Sheet1$.AreaOfBusiness, dbo.Sheet1$.LifeCycleName, dbo.Sheet1$.LOB_name
FROM            dbo.Sheet1$ RIGHT OUTER JOIN
                     dbo.CCA_Merged ON dbo.Sheet1$.Skill_Name = dbo.CCA_Merged.lN   
Group by ROLLUP (stf_now) ,dbo.CCA_Merged.id, dbo.CCA_Merged.timeStamp, dbo.CCA_Merged.name, dbo.CCA_Merged.lN
            ,dbo.CCA_Merged.type, dbo.CCA_Merged.id2, dbo.CCA_Merged.aG ,dbo.CCA_Merged.regionId
            ,dbo.CCA_Merged.sgcc,AA_Now,SLC_Today,SLCO_Today,CABN_Today,COF_Today,HT_Today,CH_Today
            ,SLC_Now,SLCO_Now,SLC_Thirty,SLCO_Thirty,ACWT_Today,CQ_Now,LCQ_Now,SLCH_Now
            ,dbo.Sheet1$.AreaOfBusiness, dbo.Sheet1$.LifeCycleName, dbo.Sheet1$.LOB_name
```

I'm relatively new with SQL Server and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Updated Stripped down script

```
SELECT  dbo.CCA_Merged.lN       
    ,convert(float,replace([STF_Now],'N/A','0')) As [STF_Now]
    ,dbo.Sheet1$.LOB_name, dbo.Sheet1$.LifeCycleName, dbo.Sheet1$.AreaOfBusiness 
FROM            dbo.Sheet1$ RIGHT OUTER JOIN
                 dbo.CCA_Merged ON dbo.Sheet1$.Skill_Name = dbo.CCA_Merged.lN                   
Group by stf_now ,AA_Now,dbo.CCA_Merged.lN,dbo.Sheet1$.AreaOfBusiness, dbo.Sheet1$.LifeCycleName, dbo.Sheet1$.LOB_name
Order by AreaOfBusiness DESC
```

```
 +----+---------+----------+---------------+----------------+
| LN | STF_Now | LOB_name | LifeCycleName | AreaOfBusiness |
+----+---------+----------+---------------+----------------+
| A  |      46 | BSW      | BS            | Business       |
| B  |      46 | BSW      | BS            | Business       |
| C  |       0 | BOSS     | BS            | Business       |
| D  |     112 | MSD      | BS            | Business       |
| E  |     112 | MSD      | BS            | Business       |
| F  |      42 | BHV      | BR            | Business       |
| G  |      23 | BCR      | BR            | Business       |
| H  |      23 | BHV      | BR            | Business       |
| I  |      55 | BSW2     | BS            | Business       |
| J  |       1 | BSW2     | BS            | Business       |
| K  |      46 | BSW      | BS            | Business       |
| L  |     112 | MSD      | BS            | Business       |
| M  |     112 | MSD      | BS            | Business       |
| N  |      57 | BSW      | BS            | Business       |
| O  |       0 | BOSS     | BS            | Business       |
| P  |      38 | MSD      | BS            | Business       |
| Q  |      38 | MSD      | BS            | Business       |
| R  |      19 | BHV      | BR            | Business       |
| S  |       0 | BCR      | BR            | Business       |
| T  |      19 | BHV      | BR            | Business       |
| U  |       2 | BSW      | BS            | Business       |
| V  |       1 | BSW      | BS            | Business       |
| W  |      57 | BSW      | BS            | Business       |
| X  |      38 | MSD      | BS            | Business       |
| Y  |      38 | MSD      | BS            | Business       |
+----+---------+----------+---------------+----------------+
```

Below is the the expected results in 3 added columns

LOB_Name2 (This is the Max of STF_Now resulting from LN)

```
57  BSW
0   BOSS
112 MSD
42  BHV
23  BCR
55  BSW2
```

LifeCycleName2 (This is the Sum of the Max of the Rollup of LOB_Name2)

```
224 BS
65  BR
```

AreaOfBusiness2 (This is the Sum of the Rollup of LifeCycleName2)

```
289 Business
```

Comment: You should really add example data and what you want as a result. It's not really possible to figure out what you need.

Comment: Hi JamesZ I've added some sample data.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can't `sum` a `max` because it would be the same amount anyhow, if you have the same group by. You probably need to have an inner and outer parts with different group by, something like:

```
select
  product_group,
  sum(max_cost)
from
(
  select 
    product,
    product_group,
    max(cost) as max_cost
  from
    orders
  group by
     product_group,product
) X 
group by product_group
```

This imaginary SQL will fetch maximum cost for each product, and them sum them up to the product group level. That's the only way I can figure out you'd actually need to `sum` a `max`

Comment: Thanks for your help but unfortunately sadly it turned out it's now what I was looking for - I've edited the post in an effort to make it clearer what I'm trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add another query level to SUM your MAX values.

The idea would be to MAX in one select and then SUM the results using a outer query. I use AVG and MAX in the example below, however, any aggregate function could be used.

```
SELECT
    LocationID,
    MaxAverageSalePriceByLocation=MAX(AvgerageSalePriceByUserLocation)
FROM
(
    SELECT
        UserID,
        AvgerageSalePriceByUserLocation=AVG(SalePrice)
    FROM
        MyTable
    GROUP BY
      UserID,LocationID
)AS A 
GROUP BY
    LocationID
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but unfortunately sadly it turned out it's now what I was looking for - I've edited the post in an effort to make it clearer what I'm trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to sum all the rows `Max` values then use `OVER()`

```
Sum(Max(CONVERT(FLOAT, Replace([STF_Now], 'N/A', '0'))))OVER() AS [STF2_Now]
```

If you want to sum all the rows `Max` values for each group then use `OVER(Partition by)`

```
Sum(Max(CONVERT(FLOAT, Replace([STF_Now], 'N/A', '0'))))OVER(partition by grp1,grp2,..)  AS [STF2_Now]
```

**Note** Converting the numeric data to float could lead to approximation issues.. Use Numeric with precision and scale

Comment: Thanks for your help but unfortunately sadly it turned out it's now what I was looking for - I've edited the post in an effort to make it clearer what I'm trying to achieve. I like the idea of OVER() and will certainly be looking at it more in the future.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You're having issues because you're trying to do two nested aggregates. This will roughly give you what you're after, if SUM(MAX) is actually what you're trying to do.

However, as James pointed out, You'll need some group by logic that pulls this together.

```
SELECT ... 
, SUM(AA2_Now_Max)
...
, SUM(STF2_Now_Max)
FROM(
SELECT  dbo.CCA_Merged.id, dbo.CCA_Merged.timeStamp, dbo.CCA_Merged.name, dbo.CCA_Merged.lN
    ,dbo.CCA_Merged.type, dbo.CCA_Merged.id2, dbo.CCA_Merged.aG 
    ,dbo.CCA_Merged.regionId, dbo.CCA_Merged.sgcc       
    ,convert(float,replace([SLC_Today],'N/A','0')) As [SLC_Today]
    ,convert(float,replace([AA_Now],'N/A','0')) As [AA_Now]
    ,MAX(convert(float,replace([AA_Now],'N/A','0'))) As [AA2_Now_Max]
    ,convert(float,replace([SLCO_Today],'N/A','0')) As [SLCO_Today]
    ,convert(float,replace([CABN_Today],'N/A','0')) As [CABN_Today]
    ,convert(float,replace([COF_Today],'N/A','0')) As [COF_Today]
    ,convert(float,replace([HT_Today],'N/A','0')) As [HT_Today]
    ,convert(float,replace(replace([CH_Today],'N/A','0'),'-','0')) As [CH_Today]
    ,convert(float,replace([SLC_Now],'N/A','0')) As [SLC_Now]
    ,convert(float,replace([SLCO_Now],'N/A','0')) As [SLCO_Now]
    ,convert(float,replace([SLC_Thirty],'N/A','0')) As [SLC_Thirty]
    ,convert(float,replace(replace([SLCO_Thirty],'N/A','0'),'-','0')) As [SLCO_Thirty]
    ,convert(float,replace([ACWT_Today],'N/A','0')) As [ACWT_Today]
    ,convert(float,replace([CQ_Now],'N/A','0')) As [CQ_Now]
    ,convert(float,replace([LCQ_Now],'N/A','0')) As [LCQ_Now]
    ,convert(float,replace([SLCH_Now],'N/A','0')) As [SLCH_Now]
    ,convert(float,replace([STF_Now],'N/A','0')) As [STF_Now]
    ,MAX(convert(float,replace([STF_Now],'N/A','0'))) As [STF2_Now_Max]
    ,dbo.Sheet1$.AreaOfBusiness, dbo.Sheet1$.LifeCycleName, dbo.Sheet1$.LOB_name    
FROM            dbo.Sheet1$ RIGHT OUTER JOIN
                 dbo.CCA_Merged ON dbo.Sheet1$.Skill_Name = dbo.CCA_Merged.lN   
Group by ROLLUP (stf_now) ,dbo.CCA_Merged.id, dbo.CCA_Merged.timeStamp, dbo.CCA_Merged.name, dbo.CCA_Merged.lN
        ,dbo.CCA_Merged.type, dbo.CCA_Merged.id2, dbo.CCA_Merged.aG ,dbo.CCA_Merged.regionId
        ,dbo.CCA_Merged.sgcc,AA_Now,SLC_Today,SLCO_Today,CABN_Today,COF_Today,HT_Today,CH_Today
        ,SLC_Now,SLCO_Now,SLC_Thirty,SLCO_Thirty,ACWT_Today,CQ_Now,LCQ_Now,SLCH_Now
        ,dbo.Sheet1$.AreaOfBusiness, dbo.Sheet1$.LifeCycleName, dbo.Sheet1$.LOB_name ) x
GROUP BY ...
```

This other question is similar- follow the pattern! [SQL: SUM the MAX values of results returned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14657881/sql-sum-the-max-values-of-results-returned)

Comment: Thanks for your help but unfortunately sadly it turned out it's now what I was looking for - I've edited the post in an effort to make it clearer what I'm trying to achieve.