# how to sum max values in application insights analytics

Tags: azure-application-insights, ms-app-analytics

we are going to collect usage metrics (meaning customMeasurements via customEvents) from our application via application insights. The data is collected if our (windows) service starts and then on a daily base via a timer.

I Know that app insights is not meant to use for "on premises" software, but we do it anyway ;-)

So we get the data from all the services that are installed at our clients. Each client has a unique id (GUID) which allows us to group by customer. (fyi we don't know which customer is behind this guid, it's just a value for "grouping" by customer)

the event looks like this:

[image]

1. I now want to group by customerId,
2. get the maximum value for a specific metricValue
3. and create the sum for all customers.

I got 1 and 2 already but have no clue how to sum the max values...

[image]

demonstrate what I'm trying to do I added a example in SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[metricData]
(
    [RecId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [customerId] [int], 
   [metricValue1] [int],
   [metricValue2] [int]
)


INSERT INTO [dbo].[metricData]     VALUES ( 1234, 1,1)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[metricData]     VALUES ( 1234, 1,2)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[metricData]     VALUES ( 1234, 1,1)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[metricData]     VALUES ( 2345, 6,4)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[metricData]     VALUES ( 2345, 8,7)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[metricData]     VALUES ( 3456, 1,1)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[metricData]     VALUES ( 3456, 1,2)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[metricData]     VALUES ( 3456, 1,1)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[metricData]     VALUES ( 4576, 20,30)


select sum(maxVal1),sum(maxVal2) from
(
  select max(metricValue1) as maxVal1, max(metricValue2) as maxVal2 from metricData
  group by customerId
) t
```

Basically the same as also asked here, but for app insights :-) 
[SQL: SUM the MAX values of results returned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14657881/sql-sum-the-max-values-of-results-returned)

Thanks for any hints

Comment: also, *"I Know that app insights is not meant to use for "on premises" software, but we do it anyway"*  is not true :).  Application Insights is intended for telemetry on anything that can send data to application insights.  the only place it won't work is inside a closed network where the telemetry can't get out.  for an on-premise app some application insights features like webtests won't work, since the webtest can't see *inside* your network.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got a solution:

```
customEvents
|where name == "usageMetrics" 
|extend cn = tostring(customDimensions.["CustomerId"])
|summarize maxValTotal=  max(toint(customMeasurements.['metric_Total'])), maxValFree=  max(toint(customMeasurements.['metric_Free']))  by cn
|summarize dcount(cn),sum(maxValTotal), sum(maxValFree)
|render barchart  kind=unstacked
```

Hope this helps someone else, as this query language is not so intuitive...

anyway let me know if you have any better solutions to this problem...

Comment: also, if your custom dimension or metric doesn't contain special chars, you can simplify tsome other things, like `extend CustomerId = tostring(customDimensions.CustomerId)`